# capture segmented audio and video with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to record audio and video from internal webcam and mic to segmented files with gstreamer.

It works to a single file by doing:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e avfvideosrc ! 
video/x-raw ! vtenc_h264 ! h264parse ! queue ! 
mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=test.mp4  osxaudiosrc !
decodebin ! audioconvert ! faac ! aacparse ! queue ! mux.
```

It doesn't work when doing:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e avfvideosrc !
video/x-raw ! vtenc_h264 ! h264parse ! queue !
splitmuxsink
 muxer=mpegtsmux
 location=test%04d.mp4
 max-size-time=1000000000
 name=mux  osxaudiosrc !
decodebin ! audioconvert ! faac ! aacparse ! queue ! mux.
```

saying `erroneous pipeline: could not link queue1 to mux`

I'm using gstreamer 1.12.3 on Mac OSX Sierra

Note: The H264/AAC encoding isn't necessary for what I want to achieve, so if there are solutions that only work with e.g. avimux, for whatever reason, that's fine.

**EDIT:** I've tried this on a windows machine with the same error.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev ksvideosrc ! video/x-raw !
videoconvert ! queue !
splitmuxsink max-size-time=1000000000 muxer=avimux name=mux
location=video%04d.avi  autoaudiosrc !
decodebin ! audioconvert ! queue ! mux.
```

Just like on Mac, replacing splitmuxsink with `avimux ! filesink` works. I'm sure I'm just missing out on some 'pipeline' logic so any clarifiction that can push me in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to send the audio stream to the audio track of the muxer like so: **mux.audio_0**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev ksvideosrc ! video/x-raw !
videoconvert ! queue !
splitmuxsink max-size-time=1000000000 muxer=avimux name=mux
location=video%04d.avi  autoaudiosrc !
decodebin ! audioconvert ! queue ! mux.audio_O
```

This happens when the documentation should be clear but you're missing out on some basic knowledge on how to interpret it.